# React Native Half oval on View

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to react-native, I want to create a view with a half oval in the bottom. I can achieve this problem using CSS, but I cannot use it in react-native as it only accepts the single number.

**Example result**

[image]

```css
.halfOval { 
    background-color: #a0C580;
    width: 400px;
    height: 20px;
    border-radius:  0 0 50% 50% / 0 0 100% 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="halfOval"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution I can say is to create a semicircle and scale it based on your device resolution. Sample code is given below

```
<View style={styles.ovalBgH}> 
    <View style={styles.ovalBg}>
    </View>
</View>
```

Stylesheet code

```
ovalBgH:{
    overflow: 'hidden', 
    width : 50, 
    height:25, 
    position : 'absolute', 
    borderBottomEndRadius:25,
    borderBottomLeftRadius:25,
    left:-25,
    top:10,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    transform: [
    {scaleX: 7}
    ]
},
ovalBg:{
    backgroundColor: '#a0c580',
    width : 50, height:50,
    transform: [
    {scaleX: 7}
    ]
}
```

Screenshot is given below
[image]

Comment: The scaleX value should changed based on device width, But here you can generalise that using  a scaled value for width. To understand scaling for different screen size see Method 3: Scaling Utils  in the link https://medium.com/soluto-engineering/size-matters-5aeeb462900a .   So you can do scale(50) and adjust scaleX value to fit your device, Hence you will get a unique design view for your ellipse , Please let me know if you face any difficulties , Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this kind of style may be your requirement would be fulfilled.

https://snack.expo.io/HkfD57Ipr

```
style={{
         width: 100,
         height: 50,
         backgroundColor: '#a0C580',
         borderBottomEndRadius: 100,
         borderBottomStartRadius: 100,
         transform: [{ scaleX: 3 }],
      }}
```